# Apache return corrcect page but with status "403 Forbidden"

Tags: apache-2.4

Apache returns the correct page, everything works but for the root document "/" it shows status 403 Forbidden. The browser still shows the page, just the status code is wrong.

Only for root "/", every other document is fine.

The problem appeared after I changed:

```
RewriteRule !\.(avi|css|doc|flv|gif|gzip|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|mov|mp3|pdf|png|ppt|rar|swf|txt|wav|wmv|xml|zip)$ /cms/front_content.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cms/front_content.php [QSA,L]
```

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian).
Webroot has `Require all granted`.

error.log

> Cannot serve directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/: No matching
> DirectoryIndex
> (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,standard_index.html)
> found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options
> directive

If I create a `index.php` in the root it shows the index.php but that is not the correct page.

Does someone know how to fix this?